# How to add https:// in url when input value with http:// or "a.com" onBlur event reactjs

Tags: reactjs, onblur

I want to add `https://` at the start of input value `onBlur` event if user has entered value `http://` or without `http://` like `abc.com` with reactjs

```
changeSocialUrl(e) {
    var string = e.target.value;
    if (!~string.indexOf("http")) {
        string = "http://" + string;
    }
    e.target.value = string;
    return e
}
```

```
<Field name="twitter_profile" 
       type="text"
       className="form-control inputText" 
       placeholder={"https://twitter.com/yourname\n"} 
       component={renderText} 
       validate={url} 
       onBlur={(e)=> this.changeSocialUrl(e)}/>
```

How to return the value to the input to change the value in input.

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeSocialUrl=this.changeSocialUrl.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      url: ''
    }
}

changeSocialUrl(e) {
        const urlPattern = new RegExp(/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/);
        let string = e.target.value;

        if(urlPattern.test(string)){
          //string is url

          ///clear http && https from string
          string = string.replace("https://","").replace("http://","");

          //add https to string
          string = `https://${string}`;
        }
        this.setState({ url: string })
}

render() {
    return (
    <input type="text" onChange={e => this.changeSocialUrl(e)} value={this.state.url}/>
    )
}
```